# Как вернуть false из конструктора класса

Tags: ооп, php

У меня при создании класса в конструкторе определяется, существует ли вообще переданное через get имя метода этого класса.

```
class My_class{
 public $error;
 public function __construct(){
   $action  = $_GET['action'];
   if (!method_exists(__CLASS__,$action)){
     $this->error = "Метод класса не найден";
   } 
 }
}
```

И при создании экземпляра проверяю :

```
$obj = new My_class();
if ($obj->error) ... и т.д.
```

Как все это сделать лаконичней? Без дополнительного свойства `$error`, чтобы конструктор в случае неудачи возвращал не объект, а `null` ? Пробовал из конструктора возвратить `null` или `false` - но объект все равно благополучно создается.

Comment: ...
if (!method_exists(__CLASS__,$action)){
     return false;

   } else return true;
... Не катит, не?

Comment: не катит. Объект все равно создается благополучно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выкидывайте Exception из конструктора. Будет что-то вроде этого:

```
class My_class{
 public function __construct(){
   $action  = $_GET['action'];
   if (!method_exists(__CLASS__,$action)){
     throw new Exception("Метод класса не найден");
   } 
 }
}

try {
 $obj = new My_class();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Метод класса не найден, объект не создан
}
```

Comment: @fori1ton, ок! Ответ засчитан! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
class xxx{
    static function create()
    {
        if ( ... )
            return new self(); else
            return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Лаконично:

```
$c = xxx:create();
if ( !$c ) { ... }
```